# Issue running nextflow on slurm incronjob

Tags: cron, slurm, nextflow

I use a bash script to launch a pipeline composed by multiple nextflow scripts scheduled by slurm. I can run the bash file manually, but it won't work ifthe same command line (i.e. the bash launcher) is run using a cronjob for the same user. In particular, in the very first process of the first nextflow, I get this error:

```
Caused by:
  java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sbatch" (in directory "/my_launching_dir/work/01/5f3db67a034dd609a15c29e53f8523"): error=2, No such file or directory

Command executed:

  sbatch .command.run

Command exit status:
  -

Command output:
  (empty)
```

If I then manually change to this working directory and run `sbatch .command.run` it runs without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sbatch` command is probably not in your `$PATH` when you run your cron job. To debug, try echoing the variable in the script using `echo $PATH` when you run it manually and when it's run using cron. They're probably not the same. You'll then need to update your `$PATH` by adding something like the following to the top of your crontab file:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work :( I think the NF error message may be tricky. Later in my .sh launcher I invoke sbatch (to launch a subsequent NF script), which works when launched manually. The problem seems to be the loading of sbatch from inside the NF process. I tried to break the nf down to a trivial script with 1 process which prints 1 file: the outcome is the same.

Comment: Ok, fixed: I had to add "/usr/local/bin". Thanks for the help!